# How Can I Hide the PDF Viewer Toolbar in CefSharp?

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

When loading a PDF document into browser, is there a way to hide the toolbar (zoom, save, print, etc.)? I've spent some time searching and even some time experimenting, but with no success.

It seems if I load a PDF into Chrome and use the developer tools, I can inspect the element and then set display: none. That does the trick there, but when I try to execute some javascript via CefSharp, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

From poking at some view source information, it looks like Chrome (the official Google version) is somehow intercepting the PDF view request and displaying the PDF in a container or frame or something of that sort that I can't directly access from operating on the main CEF frame.

Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: CefSharp is a thin wrapper around CEF. The real question is whether CEF can hide the toolbar?

Comment: @Yoshi - True, but if it can, then there is also the matter of how to trigger that functionality through CefSharp.

Comment: It is relatively easy to modify the CefSharp open source code to expose a CEF API function.  Once you find the exact CEF API function to hide the toolbar, you could post a feature request on the CefSharp github page and ask for guidance about how to expose the CEF function to C#.